# Calculate number of samples needed to prove a reduction of 5%?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm struggling to find the correct result of the following question:

"Check if the process changes have had an impact on production. The null hypothesis is that the scrap levels are 15%. The alternative is that they are <15%. You would like to prove a reduction of 5%. How many samples are needed with $\alpha =0.05$ and $\beta=0.2$?"

I guess it's fairly straightforward, but I think I'm missing something. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't "prove" a reduction of 5%. You can Reject the null
hypothesis that the defective rate is less than 15% against the alternative
that the rate is 10%.

Suppose $n = 281.$ Let the number of defectives be $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 281, p=0.15).$
Then $P(X \le 32) = 0.4967 < 0.05.$ So you can Reject $H_0: p = .15$ against an alternative that $p < .15$ at level $\alpha = 0.05.$ Computation from R:

```
pbinom(32, 281, .15)
[1] 0.04966897
```

Also, if the number of defectives is given by $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 281, p=0.10).$ Then $P(Y \ge 33) = 0.1890 < 0.2.$

```
1-pbinom(32, 281,.10)
[1] 0.1889692
```

[image]

I used a brief search program in R with binomial quantile functions (inverse CDFs)
`qbinom`, to find the value $n = 281$ (see below). Perhaps you
are expected to use normal approximations to binomial probabilties
and to solve the resulting equations in order to find the approximate value of $n.$
If so, perhaps knowing the (approximate) solution will make that task
a little less tedious. [Using normal approximations you might get a slightly
different value of $n.]$

```
n = 200:400
n.al = qbinom(.05, n, .15) - 1
n.be = qbinom(.8, n, .1)
min(n[n.al==n.be])
[1] 281
```

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting a normal approximation, and I was following this approach (by hand): https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/306/, however I couldn't seem to get the right answer.

Comment: Your problem is for a binomial distribution with the possibility of a normal approximation. Your link--not precisely applicable--is framed in terms of hypothesis testing for a normal distribution..// Not every hwk problem has a direct answer lurking on the Internet (or available here). Suggest you edit your attempted normal aprx into your question. Then maybe one of us can suggest a correction or improvement.